# Swift decodable propagate userInfo

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

I have the following models:

```
struct Shop: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let products: [Product]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case products
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.products = try container.decode([Product].self, forKey: .products)
    }
}

struct Product: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let productImageURL: String
    private(set) var productDetails: ProductDetails

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case title
        case productImageList
        case productImageDetails
        case productDetails
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.productDetails = try container.decode(ProductDetails.self, forKey: .productDetails)

        guard let serializationType = decoder.userInfo[.serializationType] as? SerializationGenericType else {
            throw NetworkError.modelParsingError(message: "Product model missing serialization type")
        }

        switch serializationType {
        case .list:
            self.productImageURL = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .productImageList)
        case .details:
            self.productImageURL = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .productImageList)
            self.productDetails = try container.decode(ProductDetails.self, forKey: .productDetails)
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the models are much more complex, but this is enough to explain my problem :)

Also, please don't mind the coding keys and the image URL, it's just to show that for different serialization type it initialized differently.

When getting the product details I have:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.userInfo[.serializationType] = SerializationGenericType.details
let product = try decoder.decode(Product.self, from: data)
```

But when I try to pass the serialization type when initializing the `Shop` in the user info of the `JsonDecoder` like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.userInfo[.serializationType] = SerializationGenericType.list
let shop = try decoder.decode(Shop.self, from: data)
```

In the `Product` initializer the user info is empty.

My question is how to propagate the serialization type from the `Shop` to the `Product` so I can properly decode it using the correct serialization type?

Comment: @Hamish the thing that you are referring is for initializing a `Product` from "outside". If you have a look in the shop for the products array I have `self.products = try container.decode([Product].self, forKey: .productDetails)` I cannot call `decoder.decode`

Comment: What's the difference between `.list` and `.details`? Why not decoding everything and process it later on based on this piece of information?

Comment: @Cristik Because for the list I receive less data, while for the details I receive the full data. Also, this is just a simple example, but for some models there is different structure of the response received from the backend for the same model. Don't ask me why :)

Comment: Then I'd recommend two structures to model this.

Comment: @Hamish Now I noticed what you wanted to say. It was my mistake, sorry. Fixed it in the question

Comment: @nikmin I cannot reproduce your problem then, because after changing that, your code works fine for me: https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/03256848da942b75a226cbf9b8400151 (though I had to guess the parts you omitted; a [mcve] would make it easier for others to reproduce your issue)

Comment: @Hamish I tried your gist and it really works, but cannot find what I'm missing. I'll investigate more and will give you details. Thanks a lot!